Inner text shadow + text with gradient background
I have a text "250" in figma with this props:

Inner shadow: -4px 4px 8px #000(40%)
Drop shadow: -1px 1px 2px #fff (80%)
Gradient: from #212423 to #0D0D0D

That renders this:

But I have tried to reproduce it and I can't find any solution to combine text with a gradient as a background and an inner shadow.
So, I just have a text with a gradient and a drop shadow to create the "light effect" but not the inner shadow.
Inner shadow: -4px 4px 8px #000(40%)
Current code
<h1 className="text-3D">250</h1>

.text-3D {
        background: #212423;
        background: linear-gradient(to top, #0D0D0D 0%, #212423 100%);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        line-height: 80%;
        filter: drop-shadow(-1px 1px 1px #ffffff80);
        font-size: 200px;
        font-weight: 900;
}

I have seen this similar question:
gradient text in css with text shadow
But they work on a gradient text with a "drop shadow" and not an "inner shadow".
Has anyone already succeeded in combining gradient text with an inner shadow?

Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes, you are right, I rephrased my question.

This question is similar to: gradient text in css with text shadow. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, I have edited my question. They work on a gradient text with a "drop shadow" and not an "inner shadow".

This question is similar to: Inner text shadow with CSS. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have run your provided code and it looks same as your provided image. Is there any detail I am missing ?

This look similar. Update values and use it


.text {
  font-size: 250px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #212423;
  
  /* Gradient text */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #212423, #0d0d0d);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  
  /* Inner shadow (mimicked using text-shadow) */
  text-shadow: 
    -4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), /* Inner shadow */
    -1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); /* Drop shadow */
}
<div class="text">250</div>



